# iOS 9 native application cannot connect to mobilefirst server by https

Tags: xcode, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I've developed a native iOS MobileFirst application in XCode 7 and MobileFirst 7.0 following the guidelines in: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-with-the-mfp-sdk/

The application is developed in swift.

I've already configured the App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 by modifying the info.plist configuration:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

This fix got rid of the SSL error I had in the log when connecting by https. However, afterwards, I'm getting this error in XCode when connecting by https:

```
2015-11-18 17:41:07.914 AdapterBasedAuthSwift[56303:764042] Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server. Response: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

With http is working fine.

I'm testing with production server, not studio.

Comment: Will u plz try with the NS ALLOW OVERRIDE ALL ?

Comment: Do you mean configuring the <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/> in the info.plist file? because in that case I've already did it and solved the ssl error I was having. But then it appeared the other error I show in the log.

Comment: @IreneMarquet, it would be helpful if you will mention what are those "ats exceptions" that you made, and where are you testing (production server or studio).

Comment: @IdanAdar I've edited the question to include the "ats exceptions" that i've made and the specification that testing in a production server.

Comment: A production server must be configured with TLS 1.2. Did you? See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Comment: When you connect, the mobile application tries to connect to a URL ending in `/init` (you might be able to see it from the XCode debug log, or in a proxy such as Charles). What happens if you navigate to the HTTPS version of that URL in a web browser? Do you see any SSL warnings?

Comment: @IdanAdar we have sent the link to the server administrator to make sure that all this configuration is taken into account

Comment: @AndrewFerrier indeed we are connecting to tge URL ending in /init. I've seen this in the server log errors when trying to connect though https:    "This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.[Learn More]". This is not seen when connecting though http

Comment: @IdanAdar we are working on enabling the TLS 1.2 too on the server, but, is this required although we have disabled the ATS from the plits file?

Comment: It is required by Apple once you go to production. During development you can disable it.

Answer (score 2):

During development time it is simplest to disable ATS like so in your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This is useful, but to be clear, all this does is allow the client to connect to HTTP URLs as well as HTTPS URLs. It doesn't make the HTTPS checking any less stringent.